# form Panel layout issue in extjs2

Tags: css, layout, html, extjs

I am new to extjs layouts. 
I have a Form panel with default layout.I am adding a fieldset which contains a grid and two buttons.  I am rendering a form Panel to div.

Div in JSP

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

FormPanel in JS

```
var fp = new Ext.FormPanel(
                {
                    standardSubmit :true,
                    id :'panel',
                    autoHeight :true,
                    layout: 'border',
                    bodyCfg: { cls: 'template' },
                    bodyPadding :10,
                    margin :'0 0 20',
                    frame :'true',
                    renderTo :'mydiv',
                    buttonAlign:'right',
                   items : [topPanel , fieldset ]
   });
```

I want the form and grid to be resized as per window size (resizing of the window shold resize the element) Right now If try I to resize the window, fieldset is getting resized as per window but grid is not.

I have given a fixed height and width to grid for now. As without that grid just expand  horizontally.

I dont want to give any height width to panel , grid. How can it be achieved? As I searched if we render panel to viewport , it will take care of resizing. If this is so , then should I create a viewport in extjs and reneder that to div? If yes then how to do that?

Edit: Or I have to use css with div?

Any pointers are appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a viewport and this will as you say, take care of the resizing.

Within the viewport, you can then add your panel the 'items' collection. If you want the panel to fit the viewport, you should use the 'fit' layout.

Something along these lines would be the right type of idea:

```
var viewPort = new Ext.Viewport({
    id: "blaa",
    items: [fp],
    layout: "fit"
)};
```

I've not checked the syntax here, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case do I need to render viwport in on div? How to do that?

Comment: A viewport is designed to fit just that, the viewport, so probably isn't the best candidate to put inside a div. It doesn't have a renderTo property. What is driving the need to put the panel in a div, could you rethink the layout at all? If not, as Varun mentions, you could apply 'fit' layout to the panel with that inside the div but I'm not 100% whether the fit layout will fill the div, as it's not an Ext.container

Comment: Ok, I am adding panel to viewport now. vieport has border layout. Added 1 panel with region: north, and adding fieldset (which contains gridPanel) with region center. But problem with Grid resizing remains the same. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor property. E.g.: `anchor: '-10'`on whichever components you want this feature on. This will automatically adjust the width of the component according to it's parents width.

So if your `formpanel` is of `width` 100px, any child component which has `anchor : '-10px'` set, will have width `widthOfParent - anchorWidth`

You can also set the layout to `fit`. This will automatically expand all child components to `width` of their parents.